# PHP function refresh page after execute (Go back to div)

Tags: php, html

I have got 2 pages:

```
Fun.php
Class.fun.php
```

In `class.fun.php` I got functions, for example, select posts/upvote post/downvote post.

In `Fun.php` I'm displaying all posts (Like facebook posts) : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtpBV.jpg)

When I `upvote/downvote` post, it calls function in `class.fun.php` and refreshes page, but goes back to top. : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1F2E.jpg)

But I want page to stay or go back to same post, where I clicked `upvote` , so I could scroll forward.

My Upvote function:

```
public function upvotePost(){
    try
    {

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

            $stmt = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$user_id));

            $myRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }

        $id = $_GET['image_id'];                    
        $user_id = $myRow['id'];

        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM fun_post_upvotes WHERE image_id=('$id') AND user_id=('$user_id')");
        $stmt2->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt2->fetchColumn();

        if($result2 == 0){

            $stmt3 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO fun_post_upvotes (image_id,user_id) VALUES(:image_id,:user_id)");

            $stmt3->bindparam(":image_id", $id);
            $stmt3->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);

            $stmt3->execute();  

            $stmt4 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM fun_posts WHERE id=('$id')");
            $stmt4->execute();
            $result4 = $stmt4->fetchAll();

            foreach($result4 as $post){
                $newUpvotes = $post['upvotes']+1;

                $stmt5 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE fun_posts SET upvotes=$newUpvotes WHERE id=('$id')");                                                                                         
                $stmt5->execute();

                $_SESSION["result"]='You have succesfully liked this post!';

            }
            }else{

            $_SESSION["error"]='You have already liked this post!';

            }

            $stmt6 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM fun_post_downvotes WHERE image_id=('$id') AND user_id=('$user_id')");
            $stmt6->execute();
            $result6 = $stmt6->fetchColumn();

            if($result6 > 0){
                $stmt7 = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM fun_post_downvotes WHERE image_id=('$id') AND user_id=('$user_id')");
                $stmt7->execute();

                $stmt8 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM fun_posts WHERE id=('$id')");
                $stmt8->execute();
                $result8 = $stmt8->fetchAll();

                foreach($result8 as $post){

                    $newDownvotes = $post['downvotes'] - 1;

                    $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE fun_posts SET downvotes=$newDownvotes WHERE id=('$id')");                                                                                         
                    $stmt9->execute();

                }
            }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is Ajax.

Comment: Use [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and don't set `#` in anchor tag if you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at HTML anchors for a very simple solution, assuming you are using a hyperlink for voting.
You would need the container of each post to have it's own unique ID attribute, which you then refer to in your upvote/downvote href attribute, creating an anchor which the browser will jump to. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp
For example -

```
<div id="post_1">
    Post content is here
    <a href="yoururl.com/posts#post_1">UPVOTE</a>
    <a href="yoururl.com/posts#post_1">DOWNVOTE</a>
</div>
<div id="post_2">
    Post content is here
    <a href="yoururl.com/posts#post_2">UPVOTE</a>
    <a href="yoururl.com/posts#post_2">DOWNVOTE</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively look into using javascript ajax to post the data without reloading the page and therefore no need to scroll at all. See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp for an introduction, or check out a JS library like jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I have already take a look on this. But there's problem. I made a div, like in example. But it won't go to div. Even if i write url and id with hand.

Comment: @crelix18 Won't be able to help with your situation specifcally without seeing an example of your code. Just make sure each post references itself in the voting links (each post should be unique), I edited my answer to show a second post/links.